# What causes the "Couldn't install on USB storage or SD card" error on Play Store?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, google-play

I just updated my application on Google Play, but some customers reported that Google Play Store displays an error message "Couldn't install on USB storage or SD card" that prevents the app from being installed.

I have not changed the `android:installLocation` attribute on `AndroidManifest.xml`, so there must be something else. Could you share your experience about this?

Comment: Just an idea... Maybe they set the SD as the location where to install any app and their storage is full?

Comment: You mentioned you did not change the `android:installLocation`. Does that mean you originally had it set to something, or do you not have it specified at all?